# Вывод каждого элемента отдельно,а не массивом

Tags: массивы, laravel, blade

Вывожу элементы из DB в шаблон сайта при помощи строки

```php
{{ $items->tools->pluck('title', 'tools-url') }}
```

Таким образом они выводятся в качестве массива в одном элементе дизайна.

```html
<span class="badge">
 <a href="tools-url, tools-url">
  ['Tools-1','Tools-2]
 <a/>
</span>
```

Как вывести их по отдельности каждый? (чтобы получилось как то так)

```html
<span class="badge">
 <a href="tools-url" class="tools-description">Tools-1</a>
</span> 
<span class="badge">
 <a href="tools-url" class="tools-description">Tools-2</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так цикл. [В документации вообще всё написано](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)...

Если Вы правильно "плакнули" данные (правда не очень понятно зачем), то выводите их так:

```
@foreach($items->tools->pluck('title', 'tools-url') as $tool)
<span class="badge">
 <a href="tools-url" class="tools-description">{{ $tool }}</a>
</span> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Если я вывожу через цикл, то получаю ошибку "Невозможно прочитать поле Title, url"

Comment: Все правильно, только писать надо без `->pluck('title', 'url')`
Должно плучится `@foreach ($item->tools as $tools }} #code @endforeach`

Comment: @Dizmuzz Так Вы через pluck преобразуете массив в 'tools-url' => 'title', у Вас в значении больше нет объекта, только строка. Ключ - это ссылка. Я поэтому и указываю Вам на бессмысленное преобразование, когда у Вас и так все данные доступны.